# После конвертации .py в .exe не могу скопировать файл через самого себя

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Здравствуйте**, уже кучу форумов перелистал, везде одни и те же подсказки, но ничего не работает...
Когда исполняемый файл с расширением .py, то все работает как часы, но стоит мне прогнать его через pyinstaller, он пишет что не может найти файл в папке temp, где он распаковывается, когда работает.
Вот функция, которая выполняется:

```
def find_startup():
    file_adress = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    adress_exp, file_exp = os.path.split(file_adress)
    logging.info(f'{file_exp} в {adress_exp}')
    disk = "C"
    for disks in disk:
        for adress, _, files in os.walk(f"{disks}:\\"):
            for file in files:
                all_files = os.path.join(adress, file)
                if 'Start Menu\Programs\Startup' in all_files:
                    adress_startup =  adress+'\\'
                    for adress_st, _, files_st in os.walk(adress_startup):
                        for file_st in files_st:
                            all_in_startup = os.path.join(adress_st, file_st)
                            if file_exp in all_in_startup:
                                print("Файл уже в автозагрузке")
                                return None
                        shutil.copyfile(file_adress, adress_startup+file_exp)
                        print("Файл скопирован в автозагрузку")
                        logging.info(f'{file} скопирован')
                        return None
```

Пробовал заменять вместо sys.argv[0] на "_ _ file _ _", так же пробовал менять расширение, но ошибка остается одинаковой:

```
        File "testdeleter.py", line 81, in <module>
        File "testdeleter.py", line 36, in find_startup
        File "shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\iGor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI52882\\testdeleter.py'
```

Задача:
Запуская файл, копировать его в автозагрузку системы или, если он там найден, продолжать скрипт. Я мог бы пойти более легким путем, вбить просто название файла и перенести, но вдруг кто то захочет изменить его? Поэтому приходится идти такими путями... Так же я мог бы просто переносить в автозагрузку и сам исполняемый файл с .py, но если на компьютере нет Python, то он просто не запустится.
Если у вас есть идеи, буду рад услышать решение данной задачи, за ранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дамы и господа, нашел решение, буду рад помочь тем, у кого такая же проблема.
Сначала я установил модуль cx_Freeze(pip install cx_Freeze), затем создал файл setup.py с содержимым:

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
    name = "Название будущего файла",
    version = "Версия файла",
    description = "Описание",
    executables = [Executable("Название существующего файла.py")]
    #В названии существующего файла можно использовать расширение .py и .pyw
)
```

1. Скопировал файл, который нужно скомпилировать, вместе с setup.py в отдельную папку;
2. Открыл в этой папке командную строку;
3. Ввел в нее *python setup.py build* и нажал Enter;
4. После чего в папке с нашими файлами появилась папка build;
5. Установил модуль auto-py-to-exe(pip install auto-py-to-exe);
6. Открыл командную строку, ввел туда *auto-py-to-exe* и нажал Enter;
7. В открытом окне выбрал следующие настройки:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

8. В расположении выбрал файл с расширением .pyw(что бы консоль не открывалась при запуске);
9. Выбрал кнопку "Один файл";
10. Открыл вкладку "Дополнительные файлы" и в ней нажал "Добавить папку", в открывшемся окошке выбрал папку **build**, **которую мы создали в 4 пункте**;
11. Листаем вниз и нажимаем на кнопку "Конвертировать .py в .exe"

По умолчанию она создаст папку **output**, в которой лежит наш исполняемый .exe файл.
**Готово!**, теперь наш файл(хоть и весит больше, чем при использовании pyinstaller) может использовать sys.argv[0], что бы получать текущее расположение файла с расширением .exe и быть независимым он Python.

P.S. Папку build можно так же добавить и через pyinstaller, но честно сказать, я не понял как сделать это, в документации рылся, но такого же результата получить не смог. Если вы умеете добавлять папку build через pyinstaller, то можете подсказать, как сделать это правильно.
Спасибо за внимание)